# Docker yarn unexpected token u0000 in json at position 0

Tags: node.js, docker, yarnpkg

Suddenly, when running nodejs containers where I mount the project folder into the container I got the error `unexpected token u0000 in json at position 0` from yarn install. I check the encoding of package.json and ran dos2unix just to make sure it was clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of digging and Googling, I figured out the error occurred after a reboot where a few containers auto-started. The solution was to stop all containers and then restart docker. I do not know if the auto-started containers had any impact on this but they gave me the clue something was not working right with docker as they were not reachable on the natted ports as expected.

Answer (score 0):

in my case same problem solve with clear yarn cache

```
yarn cache clean
```